# Open file by name in folder and get the values in range A:N

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a file1 and I need some values from an other file2. The name of the file2 and his folder is known, also the ID of the folder of file2.

How can I get the values in range A:N and copy them to file1 when I want to use Google App Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the ID of the file by

```
 myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('Put_The_Folder_ID_Here');

  allFiles = myFolder.getFilesByName(myFileName);

  while (allFiles.hasNext()) {//If there is another element in the iterator
    thisFile = allFiles.next();
    idoffile = thisFile.getId();}
```

Then use the ID to open the file

```
  var hisss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(idoffile);
  var hissht=hisss.getSheetByName("History") ;//sheet name
  var hislr=hissht.getLastRow()
  var vA =hissht.getRange("A:D").getValues();
```

Now you have the values required in the array.

Open your spreadsheet and setValues with the array (remember to match the number of rows and columns)